# Count for each day - the number of days until the closer workday

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Count for each day - the number of days until the closer workday.
It is possible to limit the number of days to look ahead by 20 days.

| DATE | IS_HOLIDAY | desirable result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 05.01.2008 | 1 | 4 |
| 06.01.2008 | 1 | 3 |
| 07.01.2008 | 1 | 2 |
| 08.01.2008 | 1 | 1 |
| 09.01.2008 | 0 | 1 |
| 10.01.2008 | 0 | 1 |
| 11.01.2008 | 0 | 3 |
| 12.01.2008 | 1 | 2 |
| 13.01.2008 | 1 | 1 |
| 14.01.2008 | 0 | 1 |
| 15.01.2008 | 0 | 1 |
| 16.01.2008 | 0 | 1 |
| 17.01.2008 | 0 | 1 |

data for query:

```
create table #tmp ( [date] date, is_holiday int )
insert into #tmp ( date, is_holiday )
select '2008-01-05' date, 1 is_holiday union 
select '2008-01-06' date, 1 is_holiday union 
select '2008-01-07' date, 1 is_holiday union 
select '2008-01-08' date, 1 is_holiday union 
select '2008-01-09' date, 0 is_holiday union 
select '2008-01-10' date, 0 is_holiday union 
select '2008-01-11' date, 0 is_holiday union 
select '2008-01-12' date, 1 is_holiday union 
select '2008-01-13' date, 1 is_holiday union 
select '2008-01-14' date, 0 is_holiday union 
select '2008-01-15' date, 0 is_holiday union 
select '2008-01-16' date, 0 is_holiday union 
select '2008-01-17' date, 0 is_holiday
```

I've tried to use the construction like:

```
select date, sum(convert(int, is_holiday)) over (
    order by date
    rows between 5 preceding and current row
) as rsum
from dic_calendar_production
```

But it looks behind. When I change 'preceding' on  'following', it throws the error

> 'BETWEEN ... FOLLOWING AND CURRENT ROW' is not a valid window frame
> and cannot be used with the OVER clause.

Moreover, it can give me the sum in the some range, but it will not stop when it reach the first zero.

Comment: What is your question here exactly? What have you tried to answer said question? Why didn't it work?

Comment: Larnu, Dale K, I've eddited the question by adding the actions I did before the question was posted.

Comment: For the error, the reason is because you have the logic the wrong way round. You want the rows *after* the current row and then up to it; that can't happen. A bit like `BETWEEN 5 AND 3` would never return any rows. It would be `CURRENT ROW AND 5 FOLLOWING`.

Comment: Larnu, the issue was because I used incorrect synthax. When I tried to use: "CURRENT ROW AND 5 FOLLOWING", the query worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you just need to put your data into groups, and then `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
create table #tmp ( [date] date, is_holiday int )
insert into #tmp ( date, is_holiday )
VALUES ('2008-01-05', 1),
       ('2008-01-06', 1),
       ('2008-01-07', 1),
       ('2008-01-08', 1),
       ('2008-01-09', 0),
       ('2008-01-10', 0),
       ('2008-01-11', 0),
       ('2008-01-12', 1),
       ('2008-01-13', 1),
       ('2008-01-14', 0),
       ('2008-01-15', 0),
       ('2008-01-16', 0),
       ('2008-01-17', 0);
GO
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT [date],
           is_holiday,
           COUNT(CASE is_holiday WHEN 0 THEN 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY [date] ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS Grp
    FROM #tmp t)
SELECT [date],
       is_holiday,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Grp ORDER BY [date] DESC) AS desirableresult
FROM CTE
ORDER BY [date];

GO
DROP TABLE #tmp;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a correlated query with *datediff*:

```
select *, 
  IsNull(
    DateDiff(
    day, t.[date], 
      (select Min([date]) from #tmp t2 where t2.[date] > t.[date] and t2.is_holiday = 0)
  ),1) Result
from #tmp t
order by [date];
```

[DB<>Fiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=80a9cae83d8c8ffb8aeeef36c43f8a45)

Answer (score 1):

```
select t.date,t.is_holiday,isnull(app.date,t.date),isnull(DATEDIFF(day,t.date,app.date),1)diff
from #tmp t
cross apply
(
  select min(x.date) as date 
  from #tmp as x
  where t.date<x.date
 and x.is_holiday=0
)app
```

You can also try cross apply-approach